# Getting different results from batch execution of FTP from Java program?

Tags: java, batch-file, ftp

I think I am going crazy. I have tried a number of things but get the same results. I tried getting the output directly using `STDINPUT`. I tried creating a batch file and then executing FTP. Here is the standard output from issuing the following FTP command when I execute if from the command prompt on Windows 7:

```
Connected to 172.29.122.77.
220-FTPSERVE IBM FTP CS V1R13 at S0W1.DAL-EBIS.IHOST.COM, 14:47:51 on 2016-05-14.
220 Connection will close if idle for more than 15 minutes.
ftp> user TSSDON2
331 Send password please.

230 TSSDON2 is logged on.  Working directory is "TSSDON.".
ftp> quote site filetype=jes
200 SITE command was accepted
ftp> put J1.txt
200 Port request OK.
125 Sending Job to JES internal reader FIXrecfm 80
250-It is known to JES as JOB03525
250 Transfer completed successfully.
ftp: 221 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
ftp> 0.340.65quit
221 Quit command received. Goodbye.
```

Here is the output from issuing the same command from a java program:

```
user TSSDON2

quote site filetype=jes
put J1.txt
quit
```

The code in the java program is as follows:

```
String command = "FTP -n -s:IC" + classCount + ".txt " + ipAddr;
if (trace)
   System.out.println("Command issued: " + command);
   child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
   child.waitFor();
```

I am attempting to avoid using the java/FTP interfaces available like apache because I want this to be a small project.

Comment: what is your infrastructure there? is that all the java program (as far as handling this process) ?

Comment: you need to read the input and the error stream there

Comment: All java. Note: It works if I invoke a batch file as a command prompt. private String FTPCommand = "cmd /c start " + "BIMFTP.BAT "; works private String FTPCommand = "BIMFTP.BAT "; does not work

Comment: Command issued: cmd /c BIMFTP.BAT IC1.txt 172.29.122.77 OC1.txt fails